# How to add Flag Link field to view based on Search Index?

Tags: views, commerce, search, flags

So, I am building a faceted search view on my product display, but I cannot add the field for the Flag link. I can get fields that reference the User's who used a flag, but no relationship that I can add, allows me to access my flag link as a field.

There are references to this problem [Add Flag link to Search Index](https://www.drupal.org/node/1918132) and [Flag Module Integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1634620), but no obvious solution. Thoughts? Recipies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work out of the box, but there's a patch for this
https://www.drupal.org/node/1362298

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for Drupal 8/9

This is how I accomplished this task. I'm making the assumption the flag has already been created and that it has "Display link as field" checked in it's configuration. Also this howto is tailored to nodes, but it can be used on any other entity type as well with a few adjustments to urls and pathways to where the display modes are edited:

1. To make the Title field configurable on nodes, in a custom module add the following hook as defined over at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/178476/5638. This only applies if the content you are working on are nodes. Custom entities can usually skip this step.

```php
function mymodule_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'node') {
    if (isset($fields['title'])) {
      $fields['title']->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    }
  }
}
```

2. Navigate to Structure -> Display Modes (/admin/structure/display-modes)
3. Click on "View Modes" (/admin/structure/display-modes/view)
4. Scroll down and click on Add new Content view mode (/admin/structure/display-modes/view/add/node)
5. Type in the name "Favorite Field" and click Save
6. Navigate back to Structure -> Content Types (/admin/structure/types)
7. Click Manage display next to a content type you want to show the favorite field for in your view.
8. Click on Custom Display Settings to expand it
9. Select "Favorite Field"
10. Click Save
11. Select the "Favorite Field" tab from the top
12. Remove all fields except your favorite field
13. click Save.
14. Repeat steps 6-13 for each content type you wish to display in your search API View.
15. Navigate to Structure -> Views
16. Click Edit next to your view
17. In the fields section of your view click "Add"
18. Make sure to Check the "For" drop down incase you want it only for this display
19. In the search, type "rendered"
20. Choose "Rendered Item"
21. Click Apply
22. Choose your options as you wish to format this field
23. Make sure you choose "Favorite Flag" from Display Mode.
24. Click Apply

At this point, if your content is indexed, you should see in the preview, the "I Like" link show up and should be have as configured. Here is a quick screenshot of a test view I did
[image: Node with Favorite flag]

And another instance in the wild with a custom entity using the OpenKJ module and the table display plugin instead of unformatted list. Flag's Javascript links work and everything.
[image]